# EF Core, DbContext Include related entities

Tags: dbcontext, ef-core-2.2

I have a db entity which has several related entities.  I want to both query the parent entity by doing a Find or something similar, but also include the related entities.  As an example,

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> CustomerAddresses { get; }
}
```

I want to query the customer and also include all known addresses.  What is the accepted way of doing this via db context?  Do I need to first query with a Where clause, then Include?  Something like:

_dbContext.Set().Where(o => o.CustomerId == id).Include(o => o.CustomerAddresses).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: What happens when you put the `.Include()` call before the `.Where()` call?

Comment: The accepted way is the way that works.